# How do you read in a 3 byte size value as an integer in c++?

Tags: c++, int, byte, id3

I'm reading in an id3 tag where the size of each frame is specified in 3 bytes. How would I be able to utilize this value as an int?

Comment: What do mean "reading"?  From memory? From a file?

Comment: In C you could utilize something called a bit field typed as int occupying 3 bytes = 3*8=24 bits. In C, this is denoted by `int int_3byte : 24` (inside a struct). I suppose C++ has an equivalent mechanism for this.

Comment: @CarlNorum Why not?  Say I need a 100-element array of 3-byte values-- it would be easier with a bit field, no?

Comment: @Alex, I'm not sure how you'd do that; a bitfield can only be declared as part of a struct, not on its own. How are you going to set this array up?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read each byte and then put them together into your `int`:

```
int id3 = byte0 + (byte1 << 8) + (byte2 << 16);
```

Make sure to take endianness into account.

Comment: Doesn't matter, they're the same in this case.

Comment: Also make sure that `byte0`, `byte1`, and `byte2` have `unsigned char` type (or have values in the range `0..255`)

Answer (score 6):

Read the bytes in individually, and put them into the correct places in an int:

```
int value = 0;

unsigned char byte1 = fgetc(ID3file);
unsigned char byte2 = fgetc(ID3file);
unsigned char byte3 = fgetc(ID3file);

value = (byte1 << 16) | (byte2 << 8) | byte3;
```

Edit: it appears that ID3 uses network (big-endian) byte order -- changed code to match.

Comment: This assumes that `char` is unsigned...  (Also, `fgetc` returns an `int`!)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: fgetc returns an int, but the only values that can be negative (as an int) are things like EOF (which I'm ignoring for the moment).

Comment: The C++ people probably hate it for using `fgetc()` at all, but I'm with Jerry.

Answer (score 2):

If your process is computation intensive, and you want to save time (esp. if you are doing embedded systems), my suggestion will be to use union/struct. This takes away the load of left shift and right shift.

```
union{
unsigned int ui32;
struct{
    unsigned char ll;
    unsigned char lh;
    unsigned char hl;
    unsigned char hh;
    }splitter;
}combine;

combine.splitter.ll = 0x78;
combine.splitter.lh = 0x56;
combine.splitter.hl = 0x34;
combine.splitter.hh = 0x12;

printf("This is the combined Value: %d", combine.ui32);
```

This Should work. If anyone feels this should not be used, please let me know the reason.

Cheers!
Aditya

Comment: Apart from it not being 3 Bytes, very useful!

Comment: @JackAvante..Well if you don't want the fourth byte, set it to 0 initially and don't update the combine.splitter.hh variable in your process.

Comment: Because there is much better way. Struct is not necessary. The problem is, it is not 3 byte conversion solution.

template <typename T>
union Buffer
{
    unsigned char arr[sizeof(T)];
    T variable;
};

Comment: @Doctor According to the C++ Standard (unlike C), it's undefined behaviour to access inactive member of union except for a special case regarding common initial sequence of structs (which is not the case for your `Buffer`). Many compilers support this and define behaviour of such accesses in a way that's intuitively expected, but it's not required.

Answer (score 1):

You can read an arbitrary number of byte (Little Endian) and put them inside an integer, using the function read of an ifstream ("is" in the code).
I use the function "my_read" for support, but it's not mandatory:

```
template <typename T>
std::istream& my_read(std::istream& is, T& num, size_t size = sizeof(T)) {
    return is.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&num), size);
}

std::ifstream is(filename, std::ios::binary);
if(!is) { /*Error*/ }
size_t y = 0;                       
my_read(is, y, sizeof(uint8_t) * 3);
std::cout << y << std::endl;
```

The important thing is the inizialization of y to 0. It prevents the most significant bytes of y to mess up the 3 byte value.

Comment: Your code works if both current system byte order and 3-byte input value are little endian. In other cases, this is incorrect. E.g. if they are both big endian, you would need to read 3 bytes into `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&y) + sizeof(size_t) - 3`. Mismatch byte order cases are a bit more complicated and would require reversing bytes.

Comment: Of course, I take for granted that we were working with bytes stored in Little Endian.

Comment: It's ok, no much problem with that. It'd just be a bit better if a sentence or two about endianness was present in your answer, as in some other answers. Also note that `size_t y = 0;` is, as currently written, within `if` statement (since it's the first statement after `if` clause). Your placeholder for error handling code could be something like `if (!is) { /* Error */ }` to avoid this. You can [edit] your answer to fix this minor issue.

Comment: You are right. I'll edit the answer right away. I didn't know that such precision was required in this platform. Next time I'll be more accurate.